# How To Split and Align Text Blocks with Animation

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-position, css-transforms

In principle, I want to do what is sketched below. The page has two possible states. In the first one, two texts (their length may vary) are centred together as a headline. For the second state, the texts are centered individually on the page at different positions. The transformation between both states is initiated by a button press and conducted smoothly.

[image: Sketch of Positions]

My code is written in Vue, but I think that I rather need some CSS help here. This is my best attempt so far.

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      solved: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change_solved() {
      this.solved = !this.solved;
    },
  },
};
```

```css
.cat_num {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  display: inline;
}

.cat_num.active {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 100px;
}

.cat_name {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 2s;
  display: inline;
}

.cat_name.active {
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
<button v-on:click="change_solved">Solve</button>
<h1 class="cat_num" :class="{active : solved}">Text 1</h1>
<h1 class="cat_name" :class="{active : solved}" >Text 2 (possibly lengthy)</h1>
</template>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqVkk1ugzAQha8yZZVIDYSo3VASqWdol5YiB4Zg1RgLDwgacffaOORHahV1A/MGv483I5+Cd63DrsUgCVKTNULTjinsdd0Q5FjwVhKcmGKUc+KLpa8ZNUhto2bFyNSywzyBgkuDz747vrn3OKkKqaxzk8yOrOTqiHtvu2IZUSlM6NuwhacbOdFmnns6fhpdQltBWGnJCa1KDy1RraBb1SrJpMi+tiy4+ysLdh+uSCN/1JnKGDLJjXFnOe1VW7EArN23Tjwj0SEk4AmjRXxiTxCnURn/5ucVPgCAJ2xgoWtjxEEOIFEdqRyWMzS6GctKQ4N0ZXhO6HYHYN2ChJ0VCtFPywKghqu5y6WEjQHkBqdvuTCWOSQglBTK9cYrMjznnMhFrWhlxDcm8LLWvSfXOoF47eXFaKf9T5hHOSzuryCvd0E21yD2PkzrCcYfu98FFA==)

The transformation works fine. The problem is that I cannot achieve a common alignment of the texts.

Any help or comments are very appreciated. It feels like a very simple problem. However, I have already spent quite a while working on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a simple positioning with `position: absolute`, and apply it to both the texts. Then we can position the texts relative to the center anchor to make them centered like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    solved: false,
  },
  methods: {
    change_solved() {
      this.solved = !this.solved;
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.cat_num {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.cat_num.active {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.cat_name {
  transition: all 2s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.cat_name.active {
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="change_solved">Solve</button>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="cat_num" :class="{active : solved}">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 class="cat_name" :class="{active : solved}">Text 2 (possibly lengthy)</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

The lengthy text might be the problem, because if the lengthy text made more than one line, it will be hard to make the transition smoother because the text alignment  change (using `text-align: left` for the second state will make it look bad, and if we use `text-align: center` for the first state, it will also look bad).

**EDIT:**
To center both text as a whole, we can use display inline for them and make the initial position to be static.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    solved: false,
  },
  methods: {
    change_solved() {
      this.solved = !this.solved;
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.cat_num {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  right: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: inline;
  position: static;
}

.cat_num.active {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat_name {
  transition: all 2s;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  display: inline;
  position: static;
}

.cat_name.active {
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="change_solved">Solve</button>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="cat_num" :class="{active : solved}">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 class="cat_name" :class="{active : solved}">Text 2 (possibly lengthy)</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as can be seen on the snippet above, it will feel like it jumps to the middle when transitioning to the second state (this is because we change the `position` property. To fix this, we might need a little javascript to keep the `position` as `absolute` and calculate the `left` and `right` values.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    solved: false,
    isMounted: false,
  },
  computed: {
    textsTotalWidth() {
      if (!this.isMounted) {
        return 0
      }
      
      return (this.$refs.catNum.offsetWidth + this.$refs.catName.offsetWidth) / 2
    },
    catNumRight() {
      if (!this.isMounted) {
        return ''
      }
      
      return `calc(50% + ${this.textsTotalWidth - this.$refs.catNum.offsetWidth}px)`
    },
    catNameLeft() {
      if (!this.isMounted) {
        return ''
      }
      
      return `calc(50% - ${this.textsTotalWidth - this.$refs.catNum.offsetWidth}px)`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change_solved() {
      this.solved = !this.solved;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isMounted = true;
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.cat_num {
  transition: all 2s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.cat_num.active {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  right: 50% !important;
}

.cat_name {
  transition: all 2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.cat_name.active {
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
  left: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="change_solved">Solve</button>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 ref="catNum" class="cat_num" :class="{active : solved}" :style="{'right':catNumRight}">Text 1</h1>
    <h1 ref="catName" class="cat_name" :class="{active : solved}" :style="{'left':catNameLeft}">Text 2 (possibly lengthy)</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```